# Using the same file as stdin and stdout results in empty file

Tags: linux, command-line, shell, stdout, stdin

If want to filter a file but if I use the same file as input and output the output file is empty. Is there another solution instead of using a second file?

```
php -r "echo preg_replace('~/\* DEV \*/(.*)/\* ENDDEV \*/~si', '', file_get_contents('php://stdin'));" < build/index.php > build/index.php
```

Comment: use the file as a basis, then create a new one, delete the original and rename the new one is not an option i assume. this could also be useful as a backup basis, since you're editing a sensitive file (an index)

Comment: Its definetly an option but there has to be another, cleaner way.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that there actually isn't a cleaner way, since even programs with an 'edit in place' option, like `sed`, *actually* create temporary files and then overwrite.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you open a file for writing with `>`, it is truncated before you even read it. That's why it's empty.

Alternative with a temporary file (yes, this is quite common):

```
php -r "…" < build/index.php > tmp
mv tmp build/index.php
```

Ideally, use `mktemp` to generate a unique temporary file:

```
tmp="$(mktemp /tmp/file.XXX)"
php -r "…" < build/index.php > "$tmp"
mv "$tmp" build/index.php
```

But this isn't really shorter or more concise.

---

My personal favorite is the `sponge` utility from [moreutils](http://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) – it reads input and then writes to the file:

```
php -r "…" < build/index.php | sponge build/index.php
```

---

Or, better yet, don't do the substitution in PHP, but a tool that supports in-place editing, like Perl with:

```
perl -pi -e '…' build/index.php
```

Similar with `sed`, here the in-place flag for GNU `sed`:

```
sed -i -e '…' build/index.php
```

And for BSD `sed`, you need an explicit empty argument for `-i`:

```
sed -i '' -e '…' build/index.php
```

You will probably have to adapt your regular expression / substitution command for Perl's and sed's syntax, respectively.

Comment: Or sed if it has the `-i` option.

Comment: Should probably use `mktemp` for the temporary file.

Comment: @Daniel Of course – added that. The OP wanted something "clean" though, so I was hesitant to include even more code when the actual solution is just to use the proper tool, for example.