# How to merge ONLY mapfiles of `ddrescue`? (only mapfile was mistyped)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, command-line, ddrescue

My system is Manjaro (Arch) Linux. I have GNU `ddrescue` v1.23-1 (recently installed).

When resuming `ddrescue`, I mistyped the mapfile. Now I have one image and two logfiles.

On Day 1, I rescued the beginning of the disk. Day 1 command:

```
sudo ddrescue -vn /run/media/ab/2Nes1T/DDRnKB1 ~/kb1mapfile
```

On Day 2, I rescued some data towards the end of my disk.
(I wanted to speed things up so I used `-N` and lowered `-c` to `32KiB`, and I wanted to recover the approximate area of my `sdc2` partition first.
My `sdc` disc has a damaged filesystem so I can't `ddrescue` `sdc2` specifically, but I can approximate its location and size with `-i144000MiB` `-s50000MiB`)

Day 2 command:

```
sudo ddrescue -vN -c 32KiB -i144000MiB -s50000MiB /dev/sdc /run/media/ab/2Nes1T/DDRnKB1 ~/kb1mapfileq
```

In both commands, I typed the image name correctly as `DDRnKB1`, but in Day 2's command I accidentally mistyped the mapfile as `~kb1mapfileq`.

I tried to merge by using this method:

```
ddrescue -m logfile2 image2 image1 logfile1
```

Thus my merge command:

```
sudo ddrescue -m ~/kb1mapfileq /run/media/ab/2Nes1T/DDRnKB1 /run/media/ab/2Nes1T/DDRnKB1 ~/kb1mapfile
```

but `ddrescue` returned:

> ```
> ddrescue: Infile and outfile are the same.
> ```

I guessed that I could make a copy of my image and do this:

```
sudo ddrescue -m ~/kb1mapfileq /run/media/ab/2Nes1T/DDRnKB1COPY /run/media/ab/2Nes1T/DDRnKB1 ~/kb1mapfile
```

...but my image files are almost 500GB and I feel it is a bit impractical to copy 500GB to fit the above command.

Is there a method to merge **just** the mapfiles (logfiles)?

Comment: Note: "damaged filesystem" doesn't make sense in this context; "damaged partition table" does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ddrescuelog --or-mapfile`.

> Ddrescuelog is a tool that manipulates ddrescue mapfiles

<sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Ddrescuelog))</sup>

> `-z file`
>   `--or-mapfile=file`
>   Perform a logical OR operation between the finished blocks in file and those in mapfile, and write the resulting mapfile to standard output. In other words, in the resulting mapfile a block is shown as finished if it was finished in either of the two input mapfiles.

<sup>([source](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/manual/ddrescue_manual.html#Invoking-ddrescuelog))</sup>

Invoke this:

```
# but see the warning below!
ddrescuelog -z ~/kb1mapfileq ~/kb1mapfile > ~/kb1mapfile-merged
```

Warning: do not redirect to `~/kb1mapfile` (or `~/kb1mapfileq`) or [you will lose it](https://superuser.com/q/645997/432690).

The result is in `~/kb1mapfile-merged`. After you confirm it's right (`ddrescueview` is the right tool), overwrite the old mapfile (`cp ~/kb1mapfile-merged ~/kb1mapfile`).

Comment: After following your suggestion, I used ddrescueview to see the resulting merger and it looks correct.
Many many thanks. I'm so happy for the answer, and thank you for your 'warning' too.

Comment: @MarkB Good idea with `ddrescueview`, bravo! I have edited it into my answer for future users with similar problems.